# Django.views is missing why? No module named django.views

Tags: django-views

I have a problem with django.views 
My Code is

template

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <h1>{{userName}} twoje wycieczki : </h1>
    <a href ="">Dodaj wycieczke>></a>
</html>
```

basic html template with url tag.

my views.py

```
def tripList(request):
    user = request.user
    print user.username
    tList = Trip.objects.filter(userId = user.id)
    return render_to_response('tripList.html',{'userName' : user.username}, context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

also urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from views import *

urlpatterns = patterns('',
url(r'^createTrip/$', createTrip, name = 'createTrip'),)
```

but i get error

> No module named django.views
>
> Exception Location:   /var/src/Django-1.4.2/django/utils/importlib.py
>   in import_module, line 35

And I don't know what is wrong because i have included django.views in settings.py and in my python console also django.views can be imported so there is django.views

I have no idea what's wrong. I have other views with url tag but there was no bug like that.
Maybe someone have simple problem. Thank's in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was laying in configuration of django. You have file settings.py and my problem was with configuration of MEDIA_* variables configuration. You have to remember that MEDIA_ROOT should be absolute path to files in yor file system, MEDIA_URL that is mapping your media file access, and STATIC_URL also should be filled. This is my configuration. When I properly filled it problem dissapeared. :) If you have any more question write.

```
MEDIA_ROOT = 'myAbsolutePath\media\\'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
STATIC_URL='/static/'
```

Answer (score 2):

What is the name of your project, and where is your `views.py` is located? Usually, you do not have such a line while importing your views:

```
from views import *
```

If you are importing views within your project, please use the name of the project as a prefix. If you have an application in its own folder, say `trip`, you need to import its view file as

```
from trip.views import *
```

Comment: But I tried to do that, and other views displays properly, also that view can be displayed but i have to delete url tag and everything works properly but i don't want to delete url tag.

Comment: Problem solved! There were a problem with configuration of static files and media. I forgot set direct path.

Comment: @Rafik991 could you please elaborate a bit on the problem / solution? The same thing is happening to me while upgrading Django from 1.3 to 1.4.5 and I don't know really what is wrong with my static files, and I receive the exact same error! Thanks!